# Spark - Parse json file which contains additional text

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My JSON file has many lines and every line looks like this.

```
Mon Jan 20 00:00:00 -0800 2014, {"cl":"js","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36","ip":"76.4.253.137","cc":"US","rg":"NV","ct":"North Las Vegas","pc":"89084","mc":839,"bf":"402d6c3bdd18e5b5f6541a98a01ecc47d698420d","vst":"0e1c96ff-1f4a-4279-bfdc-ba3fe51c2a4e","lt":"Sun Jan 19 23:59:59 -0800 2014","hk":["memba","alyson stoner","memba them","member them","member them 80s","missy elliotts","www.tmzmembathem","80s memba then","missy elliott","mini"]},
```

/*added space for the purpose of clarity*/

```
{"v":"1.1","pv":"7963ee21-0d09-4924-b315-ced4adad425f","r":"v3","t":"tmzdtcom","a":[{"i":15,"u":"ll-media.tmz.com/2012/10/03/100312-alyson-stoner-then-480w.jpg","w":523,"h":480,"x":503,"y":651,"lt":"none","af":false}],"rf":"http://www.zergnet.com/news/128786/stars-whove-changed-a-lot-since-you-last-saw-them","p":"www.tmz.com/photos/2007/12/20/740-memba-them/images/2012/10/03/100312-alyson-stoner-then-jpg/","fs":true,"tr":0.7,"ac":{},"vp":{"ii":false,"w":1915,"h":1102},"sc":{"w":1920,"h":1200,"d":1},"pid":239,"vid":1,"ss":"0.5"}
```

I tried the following:

**Method 1 :**

```
val value1 = sc.textFile(filename).map(_.substring(32))

val df = sqlContext.read.json(value1)
```

Here I am trying to omit the text which is at the start of the line.In this case, I am getting only the first json object from each line.

That is :

```
{"cl":"js","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36","ip":"76.4.253.137","cc":"US","rg":"NV","ct":"North Las Vegas","pc":"89084","mc":839,"bf":"402d6c3bdd18e5b5f6541a98a01ecc47d698420d","vst":"0e1c96ff-1f4a-4279-bfdc-ba3fe51c2a4e","lt":"Sun Jan 19 23:59:59 -0800 2014","hk":["memba","alyson stoner","memba them","member them","member them 80s","missy elliotts","www.tmzmembathem","80s memba then","missy elliott","mini"]}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles(filename).values)
```

In this case, I am just getting the output as a corrupt record.

Could you please tell me what is the problem here and how to parse this kind of file?

Answer (score 1):

Your `sqlContext.read.json` only works with complete JSON entries that appear line-by-line in a file rather than expanded or "pretty-printed." Your best bet is to do this:

```
val jsonRDD = sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(fileName).map(_._2)
```

As stated in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext), `wholeTextFiles` returns `RDD[(String, String)]` where the first entry in each `Tuple2` is the file name and the second is the contents. Only the second is what you care about, so you access the contents with `._2`.

Then you can convert the `RDD` to a `DataFrame` and apply `to_json` to the contents as described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$):

```
val jsonDF = sparkContext
   .wholeTextFiles(fileName)
   .map(_._2)
   .toDF("json")
   .select(to_json('json))
```

Comment: May I know what it does?

Comment: I recommend trying new things in the console or in your actual code to get a feel for it when you're learning--or at least reading the Scaladoc--but I have updated the answer.